# collecting objects into array doesn't work

Tags: json, jq

I have an input file of JSON objects (log file from an application):

```
{ 
  "Url": "http://bla-bla/method1",
  "ReturnCode": 200,
  ...
}
{ 
  "Url": "http://bla-bla/method2",
  "ReturnCode": 500,
  ...
}
```

etc.

I manipulate it through a number of transformation in `jq` (such as `select`, regex functions, etc.) and in the end I shape the final object

```
| { UserName, Url, Duration }
```

But I want to collect (as jq calls it) this stream into an array in order to `group_by`. All the examples I see start with array, and then have `| [.[] | { UserName, Url, Duration }]`, which works. However, if I just specify `[{ UserName, Url, Duration }]`, I don't get a single array; instead I get

```
[
  { 
  "UserName": "John",
  "Url": "http://bla-bla/method1",
  "Duration ": 10
  }
]
[
  { 
  "UserName": "Bob",
  "Url": "http://bla-bla/method2",
  "Duration": 15
  }
]
```

Doesn't make any sense!

Note - I know that I can use `jq "my rules" | jq -s` and it works. But there should be a way to create an array inside the rules themselves!

Comment: You can't go from a stream to a single value with a filter, because filters are applied to each value in a stream separately.  That's why `-s` exists.

Comment: @chepner - but how `[.[] | {Name, Age} ]` any different? after the first filter it is a stream, Docs say: If you have a filter X that produces four results, then the expression [X] will produce a single result, an array of four elements.

Comment: `.` is an array, not a stream, referring to the input of the outer `[...]`. `.[]` produces a stream of the elements in `.`, then applies `{Name, Age}` to each element, with the results being collected in a single array. The key is the outer `[...]` creates a new array for each element in the input stream.

Comment: You may think that `.` is the first filter in `[.[] | {Name, Age}]`, but it's not. The *first* filter is the `[...]` that encloses `.[] | {Name, Age}`. It takes each value from its input stream, applies `.[] | {Name, Age}` to it, and outputs a new array containing the elements of that filter. If you start with a stream, you end with a stream.

Comment: The use of `inputs` in pmf's answer works because `[...]` receives *no* input itself (due to the `-n` option), but instead reads the entire standard input inside the `[...]`.

Comment: Pretty much *everything* is a filter in `jq`'s language. `1` is a filter: it ignores its input and produces a number `1` as output.

Comment: Ah! that "first filter" explanation clarifies! so my approach with two invocation of `jq` is best.  Could you put it as an answer, and I'll accept. the answer below is totally irrelevant to my question

Comment: I know :) I've been using jq for several years now. It's just I never had a log file as input. it was always some valid JSON - like an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in `jq` is a filter. Even an innocuous value like `1` is a filter: it ignores its input and produces the number `1` as output.

`[...]` is a filter, too. For each value in its input, it applies the enclosed filter to that value and collects the output into a single array.

This means that the only way to create a single array as output is to take a single value as input. If `jq`'s input is a stream of values, `jq '[...]` will produces a stream of outputs. In order to convert a stream of values into a single array, you need to use the `-s` option first.

Answer (score 1):

As you start off with a stream of objects, you may either use the `--slurp` (or `-s`) flag to read in the objects as array members (you don't have to use another call, just begin with `jq -s '<your filter, maybe using a map>'`), or use `inputs` in conjunction with the `--null-input` (or `-n`) flag, which lets you construct the array more flexibly: `jq -n '[inputs] | …'` or even  `jq -n '[inputs | …]'`, depending on your actual processing pipeline.